# How do I call a jQuery script on site A with iframe from site B?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, iframe

I am using the script from http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/ where there is a jquery/ajax/php/mysql chat system 1 on 1.

My question is that I want to place it in domain A, but with an iframe that it will get it from domain B and have the same functionality. The reason that I want an iframe is because I want all the data to be saved into domain B, nothing on A. (cross domain)

This script uses sessions to run properly.

You can see sample here http://anantgarg.com/chat/samplea.php

How do I call it in an iframe on domain A and have the same features?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

> Scripts trying to access a frame's content are subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), and cannot access most of the properties in the other window object if it was loaded from a different domain. This also applies to a script inside a frame trying to access its parent window. Cross-domain communication can still be achieved with window.postMessage.

I think the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) will prevent you from accomplishing your goal with [iFrames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)